# How to redirect after replacing redux store id with server generated id?

Tags: database, reactjs, redux, react-router-v4, optimistic

I'm currently using `redux-optimistic-ui` to be able to render something immediately to the user while saving to the db.

Before a slice of my normalized redux store is saved in the db and returns an id, I generate a temporary id that is replaced once I get the server answer.

The problem I have is related to routing. Since ids are heavily used in routes in my app, when I generate the temp id, it is used in my url while I wait for the server answer.

I think the way to do it is to do something equivalent to `history.replaceState` with the url containing the new server generated id.

I'm using react-router v4 and I'm not sure where to do it. It seems I cannot do it directly from the redux reducers. Should I have another UI reducer that listen to the `SUCCESS` action and store the url to redirect too ? Or is there a cleaner way ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

We finally went with saving the frontend generated id alongside the database generated id in the backend and dealing only with the frontend generated ones in the API. Another solution is to use uuids as primary keys in postgresql and use uuids generated by the frontend.